# Select first element of nested list

Tags: r, list

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
x = list(list(1,2), list(3,4), list(5,6))
```

I would like a list that contains only the first elements of the nested list. I can do this by returning another list like so

```
x1 = lapply(x, function(l) l[[1]])
```

Is there shortcut notation for this?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Not much of a shortcut, but you can do this:

```
lapply(x, `[[`, 1)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 3
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 5
```

Comment: I agree it does look cooler. I was hoping there would be a shorter way to do this but I'll settle for a cooler way!

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 I appreciate the cleanness and shortness, but can you explain the "[[" ? I didn't find anything useful in ?lapply

Comment: @MehradMahmoudian, a better place to look would be "extract" (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html).

Answer (score 65):

Another possibility uses the nice `purrr` library:

```
library(purrr)
map(x, 1)
```

Comment: For those who are wondering, this works since `map` interprets numerical values as extracting, like `[[`

Comment: Using purrr::map() solves some errors by specifying the package.

Comment: Seems more robust than the accepted answer regarding nested objects of different lengths.

Answer (score 12):

For your example list you can just do:

```
unlist(x)[ c(TRUE,FALSE) ]
```

but that depends on each sublist having exactly 2 elements.

If there are different numbers of elements then you could first do an `sapply` to calculate the lengths, then compute the corresponding 1st element positions (see `cumsum`), then select those values from the `unlist`ed list.  But by that time the accepted answer is probably much simpler.

If all the sublists have the same length (but could be different from 2) then you could do something like:

```
do.call( rbind, x)[,1]
```

or some other cast to a common object.  But I doubt that this would be as efficient as the `lapply` approach.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `pluck` from `rvest` which selects 1st element from each nested list

```
rvest::pluck(x, 1)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 3

#[[3]]
#[1] 5
```

Note that this gives different result with `pluck` from `purrr` which selects 1st element (`x[[1]]`)

```
purrr::pluck(x, 1)

#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Sadly, rvest::pluck is no more https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/03/rvest-1-0-0/

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a short notation, but this can also be done with a fold:

```
Reduce(function(a, b) c(a, b[1]), x, init = c()) 

# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 5
```