# How to access very first object in differently deep nested lists?

Tags: r, list, select, nested-lists

I need to access the first element of a `list`. The problem is that the lists vary in the way how deep they are nested. Here is an example:

```
list1 <- list(ts(1:100),
              list(1:19,
                   factor(letters)))

list2 <- list(list(list(ts(1:100), data.frame(a= rnorm(100))),
                   matrix(rnorm(10))),
              NA)
```

My expected output is to get the time series`ts(1:100)` for both lists, i.e. `list1[[1]]` and `list2[[1]][[1]][[1]]`. I've tried different stuff, among others [lapply(list2, `[[`, 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428742/select-first-element-of-nested-list) which here does not work here.

Comment: So we want to extract `ts` class objects only?

Comment: @zx8754 In this example yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `while` loop :

```r
x <- list1
while (inherits(x <- x[[1]], "list")) {}
x
#> Time Series:
#> Start = 1 
#> End = 100 
#> Frequency = 1 
#>   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
#>  [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
#>  [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
#>  [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
#>  [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
#>  [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

x <- list2
while (inherits(x <- x[[1]], "list")) {}
x
#> Time Series:
#> Start = 1 
#> End = 100 
#> Frequency = 1 
#>   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
#>  [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
#>  [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
#>  [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
#>  [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
#>  [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

Comment: Love how short the code is! My code with the while loop seems so cumbersome compared to that.

Answer (score 14):

Another base R solution - you could do this with a recursive function:

```
list1 <- list(ts(1:100),
              list(1:19,
                   factor(letters)))

list2 <- list(list(list(ts(1:100), data.frame(a= rnorm(100))),
                   matrix(rnorm(10))),
              NA)


recursive_fun <- function(my_list) {
  
  if (inherits(my_list, 'list')) {
    Recall(my_list[[1]])
  } else {
    my_list
  }
  
}
```

Output:

```
> recursive_fun(list1)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 100 
Frequency = 1 
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
 [31]  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
 [61]  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
 [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

> recursive_fun(list2)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 100 
Frequency = 1 
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
 [31]  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
 [61]  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
 [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

Comment: But `is.list()` also returns `TRUE` on `data.frame`. I *think* `inherits(my_list, 'list')` is better.

Comment: @sindri_baldur yes I agree with that - and perhaps `length(my_list) > 0` in the `if` condition in case there's an empty list there is also be worth doing

Answer (score 10):

You can use `rrapply::rrapply`:

```r
library(rrapply)
firstList1 <- rrapply(list1, how = "flatten")[[1]]
firstList2 <- rrapply(list2, how = "flatten")[[1]]

all.equal(firstList1, firstList2)
# [1] TRUE
```

output

```r
> rrapply(list1, how = "flatten")[[1]]

Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 100 
Frequency = 1 
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26
 [27]  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52
 [53]  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78
 [79]  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

Answer (score 4):

**base R solution** I've just got the idea for a pretty simple function. It is a `while` loop that runs until the element is not a list.

```
myfun <- function(mylist){
  dig_deeper <- TRUE
  while(dig_deeper){
    mylist<- my_list[[1]]
    dig_deeper <- is.list(mylist)
  }
  return(mylist)
}
```

It works as expected

```
> myfun(list1)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 100 
Frequency = 1 
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
 [25]  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
 [49]  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
 [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
 [97]  97  98  99 100
```

Answer (score 4):

We can combine `while` loop with `purrr::pluck`. This avoids an actual recursive function, which could be a problem with deeply nested lists.

```
library(purrr)

get_list <- function(x){
        while(is.list(x)){
                x <- pluck(x, 1)
                }
        x
}
```

We can also set the function to be called 'recursively' until it finds a "ts" class object:

```
get_list <- function(x){
        while(!is(x, 'ts')){
                x <- pluck(x, 1)
                }
        x
}
```

**output**

```
get_list(list2)

Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 100 
Frequency = 1 
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45
 [46]  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
 [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

Comment: That is an interesting approach. Two questions: you write that "recursive function, which could be a problem with deeply nested lists" - in what way do recursive functions have troubles with that and why does a while loop master this situation better? And: what is the benefit of `pluck(x, 1)` versus `x[[1]]`?

Comment: Hi, @stats.and.r. It is more like a conceptual thing. Superficial recursion is OK in R. But deeply recursive functions can overflow the C stack. Try the following example: `i <- 1
infinite_recursion <- function(){
        i <<- i + 1
        infinite_recursion()
}
infinite_recursion()` - this creates a recursive function that invariably stops at the error "Error: C stack usage  7974324 is too close to the limit". I got `i = 865` on my machine. Although this would rarely endanger any procedure with a few loops of recursion, this illustrates the frailty of recursive functions in general.

Comment: As for my preference for `pluck` over `[[]]`, I guess it is just because I am such a fan of the tidyverse, that I naturally end up using purrr whenever I can to handle lists. `pluck` dos offer a bit of versatility over base indexing with double brackets, check the documentation, and you will see. For the current use case, I agree `[[]]` is actually even more straightforward

Comment: A Complement to my first comment. Check an alternative to the faulty `infinite_recursion` function with `while`:
`infinite_while <- function(){
        while(TRUE)
                i<<-i+1
}

infinite_while()` - this runs on an actual infinite loop, and does not lead to "C stack overflow" issues. I stopped the function call after some 10 seconds, and got `i = 114072514`

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer in the comments!! +1

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution, using `purrr::pluck` and `purrr::vec_depth`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pluck(list1, !!!(rep(1, vec_depth(list1)-2) %>% as.list()))

#> Time Series:
#> Start = 1 
#> End = 100 
#> Frequency = 1 
#>   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
#>  [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
#>  [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
#>  [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
#>  [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
#>  [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

pluck(list2, !!!(rep(1, vec_depth(list2)-2) %>% as.list()))

#> Time Series:
#> Start = 1 
#> End = 100 
#> Frequency = 1 
#>   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
#>  [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
#>  [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
#>  [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
#>  [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
#>  [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```