# Select the first element from the first list, the second element from the second list, and so on, in a nested list

Tags: r, list

Let's say I have a list like this:

`lst <- list(list(1,2,3),list(4,5,6),list(7,8,9))`

I would then like to extract the elements 1, 5, and 9. How should I do that in an efficient manner? I've come across this post; [Select first element of nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428742/select-first-element-of-nested-list), where it is suggested that one should use:

`lapply(x, '[[', 1)`

to select the first element of a nested list. I was wondering if something similar could be done in the situation described above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `sapply` using the length of the list and the function to subset the list as below:

```
sapply(1:length(lst), function(x) lst[[x]][[x]])
```

Answer (score 2):

also:

```
mapply('[[', lst, seq_along(lst))
[1] 1 5 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
library(purrr)
imap_dbl(lst, ~ pluck(.x, .y))
[1] 1 5 9
```

Or more compactly

```
imap_dbl(lst, pluck)
[1] 1 5 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the code below works only for your specific example

```
> unlist(diag(do.call(cbind,lst)))
[1] 1 5 9
```